# MAPI ConfigureMsgService fails with error code 80040115. How to solve this issue?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, mapi, exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2013

I have an Exchange organisation with Exchange 2013 and Exchange 2007 server. I need to pull some data from Exchange 2007 server and I'm using MAPI for that purpose. In MAPI, while creating a profile using a user in Exchange 2013, the method ConfigureMsgService  fails with error code 80040115. I have no idea what the problem is. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

In Windows 10 you can check the Network List Service (netprofm).
If it is not running, start it.

Answer (score -1):

The error is MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR. Is the firewall on?

Comment: Can turn it off or add your app as an exception?

Comment: I turned the firewall OFF. The error persists.  Is there any other reason this error might be caused?

Comment: The error is very specific - MAPI cannot connect to the server. Are you sure you correctly configured the profile? Keep in mind that Exchange 2013 no longer allows RPC, it only supports RPC-over-HTTP (ROH) or MAPI-over-HTTP. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2014/01/17/how-create-outlook-profile-office-365.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2014/01/16/create-outlook-profile-exchange-2013.aspx

Comment: So if I use the profile of an Exchange 2013 user to retrieve data from Exchange 2007, will I be able to do it or not?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Exchange 2007 allows RPC access. Exchange 2013 only allows RPC-over-HTTP. Exchange 2010 allows both.